# How to select data without using group?

Tags: sql, t-sql

My base data based on dealer code only but in one condition we need to select other field as well to matching the condition in other temp table how can i retrieve data only based on dealercode ith matching the condition on chassis no.

Below is the sample data:
This is how we have selected the data for the requirement:

```
---------------lastyrRenewalpolicy------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#LASTYRETEN') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #LASTYRETEN  
select DEALERMASTERCODE  , count(*) RENEWALEXPRPOLICY,SUM(NETOD_YEAR_PREM_PART_A) AS 'ACHIEVED-ODPREMIUM_RENEWAL'  into #LASTYRETEN 
from [dbo].[T_RE_POLICY_TRANSACTION]  
where cast (InsPolicyCreatedDate as date) between @FirstDayC and @LastDayC                           
AND PolicyStatus= 'Renewal' AND (ltrim(rtrim(ISCANCELLEDSTATUS)) = 0 )  group by DEALERMASTERCODE


-----------------lastrollower------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#LASTYROLWR') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #LASTYROLWR  
select DEALERMASTERCODE  , count(*) ROLLOWEEXPRPOLICY  ,SUM(NETOD_YEAR_PREM_PART_A) AS 'ACHIEVED-ODPREMIUM_ROLLOVER'
into #LASTYROLWR from [dbo].[T_RE_POLICY_TRANSACTION]  where cast (InsPolicyCreatedDate as date) between @FirstDayC and @LastDayC
AND PolicyStatus= 'ROLLOVER' AND (ltrim(rtrim(ISCANCELLEDSTATUS)) = 0 )  group by DEALERMASTERCODE
```

And continue with above flow Below is the other select statement which creating issue at the end due to grouping
:

```
 -------------OTHERYRBASE(EXPIRYRENEWAL)--------------
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#OTHERYRBASEEXPIRY') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OTHERYRBASEEXPIRY  
select DEALERMASTERCODE ,ChassisNo , count(*) RENEWALPOLICYEXPIRY
into #OTHERYRBASEEXPIRY
from [dbo].[T_RE_POLICY_TRANSACTION]  where cast (PolicyExpiryDate as date) between '2020-08-01' and '2020-08-31'
and BASIC_PREM_TOTAL <> 0 AND PolicyStatus in ('Renewal','rollover') and BusinessType='jcb'
 AND (ltrim(rtrim(ISCANCELLEDSTATUS)) = 0 )  group by DEALERMASTERCODE,ChassisNo

 -------------OTHERYRBASE(EXPIRYRENEWAL)--------------
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#OTHERYRCON') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OTHERYRCON
select OTE.DEALERMASTERCODE ,OTE.ChassisNo , count(*) OTHERYRCON into #OTHERYRCON
from [dbo].[T_RE_POLICY_TRANSACTION] OTE INNER JOIN #OTHERYRBASEEXPIRY EXP
ON OTE.ChassisNo=EXP.ChassisNo
 where cast(CREATED_DATE as date) between '2020-06-01' and '2020-12-31' and BusinessType='jcb'
and OTE.BASIC_PREM_TOTAL <> 0 AND OTE.PolicyStatus = 'Renewal'
 AND (ltrim(rtrim(ISCANCELLEDSTATUS)) = 0 )  group by OTE.DEALERMASTERCODE,OTE.ChassisNo
```

Thanks a lot in advance for helping and giving a solution very quickly ///

Comment: I think this is not attracting any answers because 1) the question is unclear 2) You gave us a ton of code that takes time to read. May I suggest to improve your question and tell us what you have already attempted?

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at this code it seems possible there was an omitted JOIN condition in the last SELECT statement.  In the code provided the JOIN condition is only on ChassisNo.  The GROUP BY in the prior queries which populates the temporary table also included the DEALERMASTERCODE column.  I'm thinking DEALERMASTERCODE should be added to the JOIN condition.  Something like this

```
select OTE.DEALERMASTERCODE ,OTE.ChassisNo , count(*) OTHERYRCON
into #OTHERYRCON
from [dbo].[T_RE_POLICY_TRANSACTION] OTE 
     INNER JOIN #OTHERYRBASEEXPIRY EXP ON OTE.DEALERMASTERCODE=EXP.DEALERMASTERCODE
                                          and OTE.ChassisNo=EXP.ChassisNo
where cast(CREATED_DATE as date) between '2020-06-01' and '2020-12-31'
      and BusinessType='jcb'
    and OTE.BASIC_PREM_TOTAL <> 0 
    AND OTE.PolicyStatus = 'Renewal'
    AND (ltrim(rtrim(ISCANCELLEDSTATUS)) = 0 )
group by OTE.DEALERMASTERCODE,OTE.ChassisNo;
```